# Unknown column 'tmp_run_date' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, ms-access

i have tried to create a table with the missing field name.. but that also wont do the job. please... can someone help me?
i am translating acces queries into mysql.....

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_101_05DetermineRunDate
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Max(tbl_101_01SelectMaxDate.max_date))
AS tmp_run_date,
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tmp_run_date)+1
AS run_date
FROM tbl_101_01SelectMaxDate;
```

Error in query!

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_101_05DetermineRunDate 
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Max(tbl_101_01SelectMaxDate.max_date)) AS tmp_run_date, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tmp_run_date)+1 AS run_date 
FROM tbl_101_01SelectMaxDate
```

> Unknown column 'tmp_run_date' in 'field list'

Comment: You can not use the selected column in the next select with some arithmetic operation need to have a full statement something as `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Max(tbl_101_01SelectMaxDate.max_date))+1`

Answer (score 0):

you cant use aliace in same field list . try that:

```
 CREATE TABLE tbl_101_05DetermineRunDate
  SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Max(tbl_101_01SelectMaxDate.max_date))
  AS tmp_run_date,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Max(tbl_101_01SelectMaxDate.max_date))+1
  AS run_date
 FROM tbl_101_01SelectMaxDate;
```

Comment: that worked echo_me. but i don't understand why...? mysql is completely new for me... thanks!

Comment: you welcome . you cant use aliace when you already selecting.

Answer (score 0):

An alias name defined at row level is not available to use at the same row level.
Instead, you can make use of user variables where you can't use aliases.

**Example**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_101_05DetermineRunDate
  SELECT @uts := UNIX_TIMESTAMP( Max( max_date ) ) AS tmp_run_date
         , ( @uts + 1 ) AS run_date
    FROM tbl_101_01SelectMaxDate;
```

Comment: thanks ravinder for the explanation.... do you know there is a programm to convert the access queries into mysql queries?